# Add custom metadata to highchart series

Tags: highcharts

I am plotting trends for which data is coming from different SQL servers.
This is the JSON I receive,

```
    {
        "tag": "Temperature01",
        "server": "SQL01",
        "data": [
            {
                "time": 1377003660000,
                "value": 10.1
            },
            {
                "time": 1377003760000,
                "value": 10.2
            }
            .
            .
            .
            .

        ]
    }
```

I use tag for series name and data for series data.
I need to be able to store `server` property to the series. How do I do that ?
The series is added dynamically.

Comment: Anyone would like to give me some directions ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
var data = {
    "tag": "Temperature01",
    "server": "SQL01",
    "data": [ .. ] 
}; //received from AJAX

chart.addSeries({
    data: someData,
    name: data.tag,
    server: data.server
});
```

Then you have access to this option via `series.options.server`.